# Confused about how the compiler includes standard libraries in c++ program

Tags: c++, include

I'am new to c++ programming and I'm a little confused about how the compiler includes standard libraries in c++ program. Say for example I want to use the **sqrt()** function. I know that I have to include the **math.h** header file in my source code, but the **math** library contains many functions other than **sqrt()**. So my question is are all this functions source code added to the program, whitch is unnecessary,  or just the function that I need?

I hope my question was clear and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Functions that are NOT templates (and not so trivial that they are just one or two lines) are compiled separately, and then stored in a "libary" (which is not the header file, it just contains `double sqrt(double);` or some such).

The compiler will (given the right compile-time flags) link to the C library that contains those functions. The linker [called upon by the compiler] will then introduce the code that was compiled when the library was built. So, typically, the source is not compiled when you build your program - it was done some other time.

The linker understands what functions are needed by the code you are building, so will only add those functions to your program, not ALL of the functions [but it may pull in some other functions than the precise one that you asked for, for example there may be some helper functions and perhaps some generic error handling functions that are needed by `sqrt`].

Answer (score 1):

No, linking means that the linker figures out which symbols (functions and data objects) from your library are necessary to build your program, and then only includes these that are.

In fact, with dynamic linking, it wouldn't even include the function itself, but just the reference to the function and how to load the library containing it.

Generally, libraries that are linked with your executables aren't *source code*, but binary objects, which already have been translated to machine language ("compiled").

Answer (score 1):

You have a confusion between libraries and header files.  Libraries are the implementations.  Header files contain the declarations.

You use `#include` for a library file so that the compiler can find the syntax and semantics of the function you use.

All the declarations (unless blocked by preprocessor directives), are parsed by the compiler and stored in a dictionary.  The only issue about you not using a declaration is that it takes up room in the compiler's dictionary.  Usually this is not an issue (modern compilers have large capacity dictionaries).

As far as adding functions to your program, that is handled during the Linking phase (usually by a *linker* application).  This is compiler dependent.  Fundamentally, only functions that are used by your program are pulled from the library (static libraries only) and placed into your executable.  Some compiler may speed up the build process and include groups of functions that are popular, but you may not use.  This speeds up the build processor but makes your executables larger.

Some library functions may use other library functions.  This means that a library function may add a lot more code into your executable.  One example is `printf`.  The `printf` function requires a lot of support, more than `puts`, because of all the formatting specifiers.  So the `printf` may include other (internal) library functions.